# pysvn client.log() returning empty dictionary

Tags: python, pysvn

i have the following script that i am using to get the log messages from svn

```
import pysvn
class  svncheck(): 
    def __init__(self, svn_root="http://10.11.25.3/svn/Moodle/modules", svn_user=None, svn_password=None):
        self.user = svn_user
        self.password = svn_password
        self.root = svn_root

    def diffrence(self): 
        client = pysvn.Client()
        client.commit_info_style = 1
        client.callback_notify = self.notify
        client.callback_get_login = self.credentials
        log  = client.log(
        self.root, 
        revision_start=pysvn.Revision( pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number, 0),
        revision_end=pysvn.Revision( pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number, 5829),
        discover_changed_paths=True,
        strict_node_history=True,
        limit=0,
        include_merged_revisions=False,
        )
        print log
    def notify( event_dict ):
        print event_dict
        return   

    def credentials(realm, username, may_save):
           return True, self.user, self.password, True



s = svncheck()
s.diffrence()
```

when i run this script its returning a empty dictionary object `[<PysvnLog ''>, <PysvnLog ''>, <PysvnLog ''>,..`

any idea what i am doing wrong here ? 
i am using pysvn version 1.7.2 built again svn version 1.6.5
cheers 
Nash

Answer (score 8):

pysvn.Client.log method returns a list of log entries; each log entry is a dictionary. (see [pysvn Programmer's reference](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html))

you can print log messages in your code like this:

```
for info in log:
    print info.revision.number,
    print info.author,
    print time.ctime(info.date),
    print info.message
```

Answer (score 2):

finally got this to work, and it seems i did not fully understand how this particular function worked, anyhow... thought i'd share with my mates!

```
    start_rev = 10
    end_rev = 30
    url = http://dipidi.do.da/svn/foobar
    log_dict = dict((log.revision.number, log["message"]) for log in pysvn.Client().log(url,
                            revision_start=pysvn.Revision( pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number, start_rev ),
                            revision_end=pysvn.Revision( pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number, end_rev ),
                            discover_changed_paths=True,
                            strict_node_history=True,
                            limit=0))
    pprint(log_dict)
```

if you don't like comprehensions

```
    for log in pysvn.Client().log(url,
        revision_start=pysvn.Revision( pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number, start_rev ),
        revision_end=pysvn.Revision( pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number, end_rev ),
        discover_changed_paths=True,
        strict_node_history=True,
        limit=0):
    print log.revision.number, log["author"], log["message"]
```

the comprehension option gives me the following

```
    {10: 'testing my commits',
     11: 'whohooo this stuff is fun'}
```